# Orientation issue iOS 8

Tags: video, ios8, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having issue with the orientation of my app. App supports only portrait mode but it plays some videos by using MPMoviePlayerViewController which allows user to view video in landscape mode.

I have used following code in AppDelegate.m for this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

   UINavigationController* ns = (UINavigationController*) window.rootViewController;

   if (ns && [ns respondsToSelector:@selector(visibleViewController)]) {
       UIViewController* vc = [ns visibleViewController];

         if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
             return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
         }
     }
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
 }
```

This code works fine in iOS7 but in iOS8 after video finished, the next view controller opens in landscape mode.
Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please subscribe this notification

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:nil];

And perform you required actions in doneButtonClicked method